# Error when running this ansible play "ERROR! 'unicode object' hasno attribute 'comment'

Tags: ansible

Here is my playbook

```
 - name: Add multiple users
   user:
    name: "{{ item[0].name }}"
    comment: "{{ item[0].comment }}"
    uid: "{{ item[0].uid }}"
    groups: "{{ item[0].groups}}"
    shell: /bin/bash
   with_nested:
     - "{{ name }}"
     - "{{ comment }}"
     - "{{ uid }}"
     - "{{ groups }}"
```

Here is my vars file

```
---
name:
 - test1
 - test2

comment:
 - "comment1"
 - "comment2"

uid:
 - 150
 - 151

groups: "sudo, admin"
```

I'm not sure what is causing this, any ideas? I believe I may need to use with subelement instead of with nested? Am I on the right track there?

UPDATE:

Changed my code but am now experiencing the following. Updated code and error message

```
 - name: Add new group if it doesn't exist already
   group:
    name: "{{ group }}"
   when: group is defined

 - name: Add multiple users
   user:
    name: "{{ item.0 }}"
    comment: "{{item.1 }}"
    uid: "{{ item.2 }}"
    group: "{{ group }}"
    groups: "{{ groups }}"
    append: yes

   with_together:
     - "{{ name }}"
     - "{{ comment }}"
     - "{{ uid }}"
     - "{{ group }}"
And variable file:
name:
 - test1
 - test2

comment:
 - "comment1"
 - "comment2"

uid:
 - 150
 - 151

group: sudo

groups:
 - admin
 - test
However, now I am receiving this error.
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'test1', u'comment1', 150, u'sudo']) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"append": true, "comment": "comment1", "createhome": true, "expires": null, "force": false, "generate_ssh_key": null, "group": "sudo", "groups": "{'ungrouped': ['127.0.0.1'], 'all': ['127.0.0.1']}", "home": null, "login_class": null, "move_home": false, "name": "test1", "non_unique": false, "password": null, "remove": false, "shell": null, "skeleton": null, "ssh_key_bits": "2048", "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01", "ssh_key_file": null, "ssh_key_passphrase": null, "ssh_key_type": "rsa", "state": "present", "system": false, "uid": "150", "update_password": "always"}, "module_name": "user"}, "item": ["test1", "comment1", 150, "sudo"], "msg": "Group  'all': ['127.0.0.1']} does not exist"}
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'test2', u'comment2', 151, None]) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"append": true, "comment": "comment2", "createhome": true, "expires": null, "force": false, "generate_ssh_key": null, "group": "sudo", "groups": "{'ungrouped': ['127.0.0.1'], 'all': ['127.0.0.1']}", "home": null, "login_class": null, "move_home": false, "name": "test2", "non_unique": false, "password": null, "remove": false, "shell": null, "skeleton": null, "ssh_key_bits": "2048", "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01", "ssh_key_file": null, "ssh_key_passphrase": null, "ssh_key_type": "rsa", "state": "present", "system": false, "uid": "151", "update_password": "always"}, "module_name": "user"}, "item": ["test2", "comment2", 151, null], "msg": "Group  'all': ['127.0.0.1']} does not exist"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is conflicting variable names. `groups` is a reserved variable and holds the groups from the inventory. And `all` is a automatically generated group which holds all the hosts of your inventory.

[From the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

> Even if you didn’t define them yourself, Ansible provides a few variables for you automatically. The most important of these are `hostvars`, `group_names`, and `groups`. Users should not use these names themselves as they are reserved. `environment` is also reserved.

and

> `groups` is a list of all the groups (and hosts) in the inventory. This can be used to enumerate all hosts within a group.

Simply rename your variable and it should work. In general it's a good idea to prefix all variables of a role with the role name. This gets more important if you use 3rd party roles, e.g. from Ansible Galaxy, just to avoid conflicts. So instead of `groups` you could use `myrole_groups` and can be quite sure there never will be conflicts.